# Autofac relationship issues with MVC using Unit of work and repository pattern

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, autofac

I am currently setting up a new MVC web application using dependency injection (autofac). I am really knew to dependency injection so i feel like im missing something. I have a working solution (posted below), but i feel like my solution goes against what Autofac is trying to do, by resolving the dependencies.

Basically, I have a service, that service has multiple UnitOfWork, each UnitOfWork has Multiple Repositories and they share a single instance of a dbcontext (owned by the UnitOfWork). I need the IDatabaseFactory that is being constructed for the UnitOfWork to be passed down into the Repository. This is to prevent a repository from disposing of a context that is being used by another repository in a singleUnitOfWork instance.

This is what i have tried.

**Simplified mockup of a Service**

```
public class NewsletterService :INewsletterService
{
    TestUnitOfWork _uow1;
    TestUnitofWork2 _uow2;

    public NewsletterService(TestUnitOfWork uow, TestUnitOfWork2 uow2 )
    {
        _uow1 = uow;
        _uow2 = uow2;
    }
}
```

**An simple implemented unit of work (interfaces based on examples on msdn)**
I left the interface out, it just does stuff that isnt relevant to the issue (we cant get passed construction). ContactSubscription is just a model.

```
public class TestUnitOfWork : UowBase, IUnitOfWork
{
    public TestUnitOfWork(IDatabaseFactory factory,
        GenericRepository<ContactSubscription> repo)
        : base(factory)
    {

    }
}
```

**Generic Repo**

```
public class GenericRepository <TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(IDatabaseFactory factory)
    {
        _context = factory.Get();
        _dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, 
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        // ...
    } 
}
```

**Database factory implementation**

```
public class UniqueDatabaseFactory : IDatabaseFactory
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();  // using guid to quickly check instances.
    public ApplicationDbContext Get()
    {
        return _context ?? ( _context = ApplicationDbContext.Create());
    }
}
```

**and the registration is as follows:**

```
builder.RegisterType<NewsletterService>()
            .As<INewsletterService>()
            .InstancePerRequest();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericRepository<>))
            .AsSelf()
            .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<TestUnitOfWork>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<TestUnitOfWork2>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<UniqueDatabaseFactory>().As<IDatabaseFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

**My Results so far**
When using the UnitOfWork as InstancePerRequest, we get good but not great results. The IDatabaseContext is shared between all instances of UnitOfWork for the owning service. Other registration methods with autofac seems to create new instance of the IDatabaseFactory for each use eg. using InstancesPerLifetimeScope when registering.

**Working (but doesnt feel right) solution**

Alternatively, this method worked, however being new to Dependency injection, it feels like im going against what Autofac is trying to do, by resolving the dependencies.

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
    IDatabaseFactory factory = c.Resolve<IDatabaseFactory>();
    GenericRepository<ContactSubscription> repo = c.Resolve<GenericRepository<ContactSubscription>>(
        new NamedParameter("factory", (object)factory));

    return new TestUnitOfWork(factory, repo);
}).AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I strongly feel like the solution above is not ideal (with the little knowledge i have with loc containers), and instead of causing myself more headaches down the road, i want to see if there is a more effecient way to have IDatabaseFactory that is being constructed by Autofac for the UnitOfWork to pass the same instances down to the repository, but not keep the same instance for other UnitOfWork.

My project is a mess right now so hopefully the example code doesnt have any typos or old variables i missed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a little break, I found a solution to my problem. Since the UnitOfWork is already abstracting the database context, and the UnitOfWork is a dependency that is injected, each UnitOfWork now control the creation and lifetime of each repository. It was unnecessary to have the repositories injected.

Here was my solution:

```
public interface INewsletterUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<Newsletter> NewsLetters { get; }
    IRepository<ContactSubscription> ContactSubscriptions { get; }
}

public class NewsletterUnitOfWork : UowBase, INewsletterUnitOfWork
{
    private IRepository<Newsletter> _newsletters;
    public IRepository<Newsletter> NewsLetters
    {
        get { return _newsletters ?? (_newsletters = new GenericRepository<Newsletter>(Context)); }
        private set { _newsletters = value; }

    }
    private IRepository<ContactSubscription> _contactSubscriptions;
    public IRepository<ContactSubscription> ContactSubscriptions
    {
        get { return _contactSubscriptions ?? (_contactSubscriptions = new GenericRepository<ContactSubscription>(Context)); }
        private set { _contactSubscriptions = value; }

    }

    public NewsletterUnitOfWork(IDatabaseFactory factory)
        : base(factory)
    { }
}
```

and the registration is nice, simple and clean.

```
        builder.RegisterType<DefaultDatabaseFactory>().As<IDatabaseFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<NewsletterUnitOfWork>()
            .AsSelf()
            .As<INewsletterUnitOfWork>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```